# How to force persistent connection in squid

Tags: squid, connection

How do I make a persistent connection in squid, I'm using ubuntu 12 with squid 3.1.19, this is the request I do

```
OPTIONS http://cmsprod.imusica.com.br/index.php HTTP/1.1
```

and response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 19 Jun 2016 04:19:18 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=jljofpeo2imr8bbcnnb7vl4i92; path=/
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
X-Served-By: bdvpcmap11
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: CM=OIHFBLKM; Expires=Sun, 19-Jun-2016 04:54:01 GMT; Path=/
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:8080
Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)
Connection: close  <-- not persisten connection
```

This is my configuration file

```
http_port 8080 transparent
cache_mem 3 GB
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 8000 16 256
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
http_access allow all
```

I have tried various forms does not work I appreciate any suggestions, I need to establish a persistent connection with the OPTIONS method.

skusmi my english. :(

Answer (score 1):

Squid-3 default behaviour is to use persistent connections as much as possible unless you explicitly disable them.

In this case the response message has no Content-Length header and Squid-3.1 is HTTP/1.0 software not capable of generating HTTP/1.1 chunked encoding to clients. The only possible way to end that message is to close the connection. That is what the header you are seeing means.

To get more use of persistent connections you need to upgrade your Squid.